# How to change selected text and checkbox blue color to gray in ng-multiselect-dropdown Angular 7

Tags: css, angular, multi-select

I'm working on the ng-multi-select dropdown (in angular7) and I'm able to make changes to the width size externally. However, I'm not able to change the color of the selected text nor change the checkbox color. In short, I need to change the color blue to gray. I've tried different solutions with no success. Can I anyone see form my code below what I'm doing wrong?

[image: sample image]

Comment: Do you mean like this?? https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-multiselect-dropdown-qycjzz

Comment: Try solutions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53045955/changing-css-of-ng-multiselect-dropdown).

Comment: yes it works ,Missed up the html #multiselect part instead was using class and my css class name.

Answer (score 0):

For Angular v8, adding this CSS style should do the trick :

```
.mat-primary .mat-option.mat-selected:not(.mat-option-disabled) {
     color: #17c017 !important;
}

.mat-primary .mat-pseudo-checkbox-checked, 
.mat-primary .mat-pseudo-checkbox-indeterminate {
     background: #17c017 !important;
}
```